# Django Model method test

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I have model like this:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        name = self.name
        surname = self.surname
        if self.surname is None:
            surname = ''
        if self.name is None:
            name = ''
        return str(name) + ' ' + str(surname)
```

I want to write a test case for **get_full_name** method.
Currently I wrote something like this:

```
class TestUsersModel(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data1 = Users.objects.create(name='Bob', pin='1')
        self.data2 = Users.objects.create(surname='Alex', pin='2')

    def test_users_model_entry(self):
        data = self.data1
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(data, Users))

    def test_users_full_name_only_name(self):
        data = self.data1.get_full_name()
        self.assertEquals(data,'Bob ')

    def test_users_full_name_only_surname(self):
        data = self.data2.get_full_name()
        self.assertEquals(data,' Alex')
```

but when I check with coverage it says me that I have to write test case for this:
[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: `name = models.CharField(max_length=64)` according to your definition of name attribute it cannot be null so when you test it using `Users.objects.create(surname='Alex', pin='2')` check the value of surname using `self.data2.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sevdimali - Firstly, it is a bad idea to name a field as name and not first_name when you have the other field as surname. Also, if you decide to use first_name then the other field should be last_name. Consistency matters.

```
 class Users(models.Model):
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True)#or else you cannot test #object creation without name
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

Now, to test your get_full_name(). How about we do something like this?

     def setUp(self):
         self.user = Users.objects.create(name='test', surname='world',pin='1234')
         self.user_without_surname = Users.objects.create(name='test',pin='12345')
         self.user_without_name=Users.objects.create(surname='world',pin='123456')
     
     def test_get_full_name_with_valid_name_and_surname(self):
         expected = str(self.user.name) + ' ' + str(self.user.surname)
         actual = 'test world'
         self.assertEquals(expected,actual)
     
     def test_get_full_name_with_empty_surname(self):
        expected = str(self.user.name) + ' ' +''
        actual = 'test '
        self.assertEquals(expected,actual)
     def test_get_full_name_with_empty_name(self):
        expected = '' + ' ' +str(self.user.surname)
        actual = ' world'
        self.assertEquals(expected,actual)
```

Key things to refactor-

1. IMO, the Model name should not be plural
2. Name doesn't make sense. Be explicit. first_name,middle_name,last_name if needed
3. Think about null columns and the consequences they might have. You don't want to have a user without even the first_name, last_name, email, and other essential fields.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesn't work. I checked with coverage it indicates that I need test

Comment: @sevdimali- Did you change name = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True)

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment (#or else you cannot test #object creation without name). Nope I am not able to change this field.

Comment: @sevdimali- That is why your coverage is not covering that line of code because in one end in your model you specified name cannot be null and on the other hand in your get_full_name you have a block of code with if name==None. You are contradicting your logic. Choose one

Comment: yes, I understand)))  Maybe I will change get_full_name method. as I said before. Not able to change name field.

Comment: @sevdimali- You dont need to check the name==None block. Get rid of it as it will never happen